# Null reference used for synchronization (monitor-enter)

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, garbage-collection, finalizer

When I turn off my Internet connection and log out from Firebase app, I can't return my app.

Also get next error:

```
2019-11-05 20:26:19.364 5593-5611/com.mandarine.target_list E/System:
    Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer 2019-11-05 20:26:19.3655593-5611/com.mandarine.target_list E/System:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null reference used for synchronization (monitor-enter)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1053)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:252)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

It only happens when I turn off the Internet.

Also i found this: https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/master/common/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java#L1079

But don't really know what to do gotta get

Also i made `/gradlew app:androidDependencies` and get:

```
> releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
> +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.50@jar
> +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50@jar
> +--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1@aar
> +--- androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0@aar
> +--- com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0@aar
> +--- me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2@aar
> +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2@aar
> +--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3@aar
> +--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0@aar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0@aar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0@aar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6@aar
> +--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0@aar
> +--- com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1@aar
> +--- androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0@aar
> +--- junit:junit:4.12@jar
> +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:2.16.0@jar
> +--- androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.0.0@aar
> +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50@jar
> +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0@aar
> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:16.0.1@aar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:16.0.1@aar
> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1@aar
> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0@aar
> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:16.0.0@aar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.0@aar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.1@aar
> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1@aar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.4@aar
> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1@aar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.1@aar
> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1@aar
> +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0@aar
> +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1@aar
> +--- androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.1@aar
> +--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
> +--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0@aar
> +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
> +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
> +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0@jar
> +--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3@jar
> +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:16.0.1@aar
> +--- org.threeten:threetenbp:1.4.0:no-tzdb@jar
> +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3@jar
> +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9@jar
> +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.7.9@jar
> +--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6@jar
> +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.50@jar
>  \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0@jar
```

Comment: What's the code that produces this exception?

Comment: @AlexMamo does not point to specific code as is normally done, also updated question

Comment: @AlexMamo i think that my problem with `ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket`, namely with method `finalize()`

Comment: It's a good question but unfortunately, in this case, I cannot be much of a help.

Comment: @Morozov, Did you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using an older version of Conscrypt?  That bug appears to have been fixed, about two years ago, here:

https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/803bfd2af9f4bffc4fbc89f78844c7c31d12859f/common/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java#L1079

*Amended to add:*
The dependency graph is very helpful.  If that is complete (all transitive dependencies) then you do not include the conscrypt library at all.  That would imply that some *other* library in your dependency chain has included the conscrypt *source* directly.  That would explain a lot.

A quick grep of the `androidx` sources suggests that they are not the problem.

Comment: as I understand it, I need to check in all my dependencies if I am not using this old Conscrypt library?

Also yours answer is copying my link which i found.

Comment: Yeah... As you surely noticed, the error you are seeing cannot be caused by the code at that link.  I definitely think you need to check your dependencies.

Comment: updated question, and i didn't find this library in my dependencies

Comment: I am getting the same error in my Flutter app, when I disconnect from the internet and then reconnect. The dependencies I have set up are based on the instructions of the various Flutter packages I use, so any guidance on how to check all dependencies would be appreciated.